# Advanced Search: Distinguishing upvotes from downvotes

Tags: support, search

The [advanced search help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) describes the `score:n` filter.  Is there a filter for number of downvotes?  I.e. is there a way to express the condition

```
score >= 3 AND downvotes == 0
```

Comment: a downvote filter might remove better posts from the search. in your current condition you may miss out of answers which got 5 upvotes but 2 downvotes. while in an ideal world an answer with a score of 3 and 0 downvotes should be the better one this is no way near an ideal world and we unfortunately can't ignore the possibility of [tim loosing his keys](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/250962), people downvoting a bad answer which got improvced but the votes weren't reversed after the edit, other people gaming the system or any other odd reason for a downvote other than it being wrong

Comment: Well, I'm looking for the holy grail of _good questions_. The noise level has gotten so bad I spend all my time downvoting, VTCing and copy/pasting standard comments.  I'm through with all that so I'm trying to devise a filter that will give me interesting questions worth spending some time on.  My current filter is `is:q score:3 hasaccepted:no [java] answers:0 duplicate:no closed:no` but I'm finding that many of those are marginal and unanswerable, and have accumulated the upvotes just because there are no answers and they've been there for a while.

Comment: Unfortunately, even if you were to crack this nut, it won't give you a holy grail of good questions. There are lots of bad questions that have no downvotes because people are too reluctant to downvote bad questions. Some of these bad questions even get *upvotes* for inexplicable reasons. Sad to say, in the current state, if you're not spending most of your time downvoting and voting to close, you are contributing to the problem. You might feel better and waste less of your time if you stopped leaving comments.

Comment: wouldn't this bypass the [Established User](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) privilege?